# How to make my program faster for pattern matching?

Tags: r, vector, time-complexity

I don't like the way I have coded this and I think there should be far faster algorithms than this or R might have facilities to work this out.

```
    four.in.a.row = function(player, v, debug=TRUE) {
  if (debug) {
    cat(sep="", "four.in.a.row(player=", player, ", v=", v, ")\n")
  }
  for (i in 1:(length(v)-4))
    if (v[i]==player)
      if (v[i]==v[i+1])
        if (v[i+1]==v[i+2])
          if (v[i+2]==v[i+3])

          return(TRUE)
  # ...
  return(FALSE) 
}
#   four.in.a.row("X", c("O","X","X","X","X","O"))
# is TRUE, while
#   four.in.a.row("O", c("O","X","X","X","X","O"))
# is FALSE.
```

Please let me know how the complexity can be improved. Also can you please tell me what is the complexity of the current algorithm?

Also when I use the following I receive an error:

```
four.in.a.row = function(player, v, debug=TRUE) {
  if (debug) {
    cat(sep="", "four.in.a.row(player=", player, ", v=", v, ")\n")
  }


 for (i in 1:(length(v)-4))
  { 
    count=1
    if (v[i]==player)
      for (j in i+1:i+3)
        if (v[i]==v[j])
          count=count+1
    if (count==4) 
      return(TRUE)
  }
  # ...
  return(FALSE) # correct this return() statement
}

Error in if (v[i] == v[j]) count = count + 1 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rle`:

```
four.in.a.row <- function(player, v) {
  with(rle(v), any(lengths >= 4 & values == player))
}
```

Here is a more cryptic approach that should be even faster:

```
four.in.a.row <- function(player, v) {
  x <- player == v
  in.a.row <- seq_along(x) - cummax(seq_along(x) * !x)
  any(in.a.row >= 4)
}
```

Finally, you could use regular expressions:

```
four.in.a.row = function(player, v) {
  x <- paste(v, collapse = "")
  pattern <- paste(rep(player, 4), collapse = "")
  grepl(pattern, x)
}
```

You would have to test on your data to see which approach is faster. If fast enough, I would go with the `rle` approach for its conciseness.

Comment: What are your typical input sizes?

Comment: Also how are you returning true and false? I am not familiar with this function

Comment: `any` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: It's a connect 4 board like 6*7 but I don't think you need to check for `lengths >= 4` and I think `lengths== 4` is ok , right?

Comment: Please let me know if you are aware of its time complexity

Comment: `rle` is fast, much faster than a lot of `for` loops. On such small input sizes, I think you should be happy with it. The code is rather short too.

Comment: `lengths == 4` should indeed be enough if you are guaranteed the game stopped when one player got four in a row.